# How to install dlt-viewer on Linux / Ubuntu?

Tags: logging, dlt-daemon

How to install dlt-viewer on Linux / Ubuntu ?

I'm having an Ubuntu machine which is running bare minimum OS(16.04). I wanted to install dlt-viewer for viewing the logs. First way is to build the binary using github.com. I would like to install a pre-compiled source code of dlt-viewer since I don't want to build and generate a binary as well as I'm not interested in modifying the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps for installing dlt-viewer**

1. Open a terminal and trigger installation using below command

> `sudo apt-get install dlt-viewer`

2. If step#2 fails, add the repository to the apt path and sync the packages

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costamagnagianfranco/locutusofborg-ppa && sudo apt-get update`

3. Install dlt-viewer

> `sudo apt-get install dlt-viewer`

4. If step#3 fails due to to any missing dependencies, trigger below two commands

> `sudo apt-get -f install   sudo apt-get install dlt-viewer`